# getting data from gridview returns nothing

Tags: asp.net

i like to get data from second column of my grid view by code like below, but it returns nothing (di.Cells[1].Text) , please help what is the problem:

```
protected void btnShowAddTransmittaltoCon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Transmittallistfortest transmittalList = (Transmittallistfortest)DetailsView1.FindControl("Transmittallistfortest1");
    GridView g3 = transmittalList.FindControl("GridViewTtransmittals") as GridView;
    foreach (GridViewRow di in g3.Rows)

    {

        RadioButton rad = (RadioButton)di.FindControl("RadioButton1");
        //Giving Error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        if (rad != null && rad.Checked)
        {
            var w = di.RowIndex;

            Label1.Text = di.Cells[1].Text;
        }
```

the aspx is like below:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridViewTtransmittals" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          BorderStyle="None" ShowHeader="False" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="TransID"  onrowdatabound="GridViewTtransmittals_RowDataBound"
        onrowdeleting="GridViewTtransmittals_RowDeleting">
          <columns>
              <asp:TemplateField>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="Transmittal" AutoPostBack="True" 
        OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" />

                  </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:hyperlinkfield DataNavigateUrlFields="TransId" 
              DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Copy of Transmittal.aspx?TransId={0}" DataTextField="TRANSMITTAL" 
              HeaderText="Transmittal" />
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this code

```
var result = ((HyperLink)di.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works very good for me. just i like to know what does mean  Controls[0] in the above code

Comment: I'am happy to help you masoud, Controls[0] means control in first position so index equals to 0